# AvroDeserialisation Failing when deriving a col using sum but is successful when the same column is derived using count.Serialised data is in kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-avro

Here is my SQL which works :

```
  select hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid, total_failure,total_count,date_format(timestamp(unix_timestamp(window.start)),\"yyyyMMdd\") as eventdate, date_format(timestamp(unix_timestamp(window.start)),\"HH:mm\") as start from (select hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid,window(event_timestamp, '#window'),count(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_failure ,count(*) as total_count from #kpi group by hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid,window(event_timestamp, '#window'))
```

Here is my SQL that gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in avro:

```
select hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid, total_failure,total_count,date_format(timestamp(unix_timestamp(window.start)),\"yyyyMMdd\") as eventdate, date_format(timestamp(unix_timestamp(window.start)),\"HH:mm\") as start from (select hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid,window(event_timestamp, '#window'),sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_failure ,count(*) as total_count from #kpi group by hostnetworkid,roamertype,carrierid,window(event_timestamp, '#window'))
```

Can anyone help with this , why deserialisation with the below avro schema for count is working but not working for sum.Here is my avro schema file

```
{"record","name":"MapKpi7","namespace":"com.mobileum",
              "fields":[{"name":"hostnetworkid","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"roamertype","type":["int","null"]}, {"name":"carrierid","type":["int","null"]}, {"name":"total_failure","type":"long"},{"name":"total_count","type":"long"},{"name":"eventdate","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"start","type":["string","null"]}]}
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:402)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by definining the total_failure schema as a union:
{"name":"total_failure","type":["long","null"]}
instead of
{"name":"total_failure","type":"long"},